# How to remove new-line characters from in between a line without removing the new-line from end of the line python?

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing, csv

My input is a big csv file with rows like:

```
"7807371008","Sat Jan 16 00:07:46 +0000 2010","@bigg_robb welcome to the party life of politics","T 33.417474,-86.705343","al","23845121","1381","502","Wed Mar 11 22:38:27 +0000 2009","2468"
```

My desired output is a new file with first and 3rd columns only with all special characters removed:

```
7807371008,  bigg robb welcome to the party life of politics
```

But there are some lines wich newline characters in between the text even though it is not technically the end of that row. In such cases, I'm getting the error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

An example of such rows is:

```
"7807376607","Sat Jan 16 00:07:57 +0000 2010","RT @CBS8News:The commander of Gov. Riley's task
force on illegal gambling resigns after winning $2,300 at a MS casino.
gt;#conflictofinterest","Montgomery, Alabama","al","33358058","84","164","Mon Apr 20 00:48:37 +0000 2009","4509"
```

My code is:

```
import csv
import sys
import re

with open('al.csv') as f:
    for line in f:

        j = next(csv.reader([line]))
        id1 = j[0]
        id2 = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9\.]+',' ',id1)
        tt1 = j[2]
        tt2 = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9\.]+',' ',tt1)
        print id2.strip()+", "+tt2.lower()
```

How do I resolve this? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specified the comma `,` as your csv file delimiter (or a correct delimiter based on your file) also csv reader object hasn't lines that you loop over that you need to access to rows by looping over a `reader` object (`spamreader`) :

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('al.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
...     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
...     for row in spamreader:
            print re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9\.]+',' ',row[2]) + row[0]
```

Comment: you just said the `delimiter` should be `,` ?...or I was wrong in understanding you?

Comment: @KhalilAmmour-خليلعمور Not just that! actually i'm waiting for OP's response because it's more depends on file structure!

Comment: @user3292085 Welcome! if it was helpful you can tell this to community by voting and accepting the answer! ;)